# MMS in twilio with Background image

Tags: twilio

I need help with twilio. On a form submission we send a sms on the user's phone.

But now I want to send an SMS with background image or an MMS. I need to send a background image and over that few texts and links.

I tried the html code but it didn't rendered and displayed the html code instead of MMS.

Does any one know about it? How can I send background image and some links over it from twilio?

Any response would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

SMS/MMS applications do not support setting images as backgrounds or using HTML. The limits are very much that you can [send some text and you can send images](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) (or other files) and the SMS/MMS application on the receiving device will display the message as text and then the images.

If you really wanted text to appear over the image, you could programatically generate the images with the text on top and just send the image, however you still wouldn't get hyperlinks in that. It would also tie the text up in the image which would be unreadable by assistive technology, so useless to the visually impaired.

Sorry I can't help more, but the limitations are within the existing SMS/MMS applications.